# Using generic event with Otto event bus

Tags: android, otto

I use Otto event bus to subscribe for Volley Requests. I want to use this generic class but the wrong fragment (subscriber) tries to handle the event. Is it possible to use a generic class or is randomly every subscriber of the VolleyResultEvent, independent of the generic type, called?

```
public class VolleyResultEvent<T> {

    public final VolleyResult result;
    public final T content;

    public VolleyResultEvent(VolleyResult result, T content) {
        this.result = result;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public enum VolleyResult {
        SUCCESS, ERROR
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every subscriber of `VolleyResultEvent` will be called regardless of type generics. Either would you want to make several subclasses of `VolleyResultEvent` according to the number of types you're having; or implement a matching function which, for example, would compare event id (or type) with subscriber's id (or type) and allow further processing if those are equal.

Comment: way is it like this? different generics should actually be different type, aren't they?

Comment: This is a result of type erasure in Java :/ See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html